# Database service likely hang at some moments

Tags: windows-server, mariadb-10.1

Our team adopted MariaDB to replace SQL Server 2008 last year end. There is no issue for DB service hanging, and last week and yesterday I met 2 services hang issues. The following are configurations and operations.

## Configurations

1. The MariaDB version 10.1.18 has been installed on MicroSoft Cluster
   Services (MSCS). (Windows Server 2012 R2)
2. There are 2 VMs for The MSCS with active-standby mode.
3. The shared storage (Data Files) is on NetApp Storage, using raw device mapping (RDM).
4. There is a Slave DB VM for DB replication. (read-only)

## Issues

1. When the service hang, I logged into the DB VM, and I could see the DB service (mysqld) was active, and the port was bound by mysqld service.
2. From localhost of DB VM or console I could not telnet or used tool to connect DB service.
3. There was no error message in Mariadb errorlog or windows events.
4. In order to recover services quickly, I rebooted the DB VM to force the cluster hand-over to another DB VM.
5. In the recent DB VM or standby DB VM, there was no errorlog or error events in windows event. (there is only mysqld normally shutdown messages)

## Operations

1. Before the first hang, I copy the DB backup file to Slave DB, because the replication was far from current, I wanted to restore the database and made replication again. In copy progress after 10 mins, the services start to hang.
2. Before the second hang, I started replication and `show slave status` said Queuing logs and then Waiting logs, and after few mins the services hang again.

## How to find true evidence

I think the problem could be on file system or storage, but in db logs or windows event I can not find evidences to prove it. Could somebody help me to more advance method to find out root cause?

## Update

This question is issued in [MDEV-13025](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13025) and wait for next time to gather data.